# django userprofile nested relationship is empty in django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hello I have an UserProfile model in django, and I want to serialize my User model with its UserProfile nested to receive it via ajax in my template but it cames empty.

Model UserProfile

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name="pertenece_a")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'UserProfile'

    def user_profile(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
        Userprofile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

    signals.post_save.connect(user_profile, sender=User)
```

Serializers

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ["departamento"]

class GestionUsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id","username","email","first_name","last_name","profile"]
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a simple (and in this case thus *empty*) serializer, you should use a `ModelSerializer`, otherwise it will not do anything with the `Meta` inner class:

```
#                         ModelSerializer 🖟
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['departamento']
```

Comment: thank you! All morning trying to solve this problem and I didn't see the error!